# Obtener el dia de la semana de una fecha sacada de sqlite swift

Tags: swift2, swift, datetime, date

Estoy haciendo una funcion en `swift` que me formate a una fecha que saco de la base de datos `sqlite` y la muestre con el siguiente formato: `Miércoles, 07 de septiembre de 2016 a las 10:03:56`.

Tengo casi todo, solo me falta poder obtener el nombre del dia de la semana, que no se como hacerlo.

Mi código:

```
func formatFechaHuman(fecha: String) -> String {
        var nuevaFecha = String()
        let arrayString = fecha.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        let hora = arrayString[1]
        let partesFecha = arrayString[0]
        let componentesFecha = fecha.componentsSeparatedByString("-")
        let year = componentesFecha[0]
        let month = componentesFecha[1]
        let day = componentesFecha[2]
        var mesFecha = ""

        switch (month) {
            case "01":
                mesFecha = "Enero"
                break

            case "02":
                mesFecha = "Febrero"
                break

            case "03":
                mesFecha = "Marzo"
                break

            case "04":
                mesFecha = "Abril"
                break

            case "05":
                mesFecha = "Mayo"
                break

            case "06":
                mesFecha = "Junio"
                break

            case "07":
                mesFecha = "Julio"
                break

            case "08":
                mesFecha = "Agosto"
                break

            case "09":
                mesFecha = "Septiembre"
                break

            case "10":
                mesFecha = "Octubre"
                break

            case "11":
                mesFecha = "Noviembre"
                break

            case "12":
                mesFecha = "Diciembre"
                break

            default:
                mesFecha = ""
                break
        }

        nuevaFecha = ", " + month + " de " + mesFecha + " de " + year + " a las " + hora

        return nuevaFecha
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo. Para mí la mejor es utilizar [NSDateComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/) y utilizando `weekday`. Si definimos la función `getDayOfWeek`:

```
func getDayOfWeek(today:String)->Int {

    let formatter  = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let todayDate = formatter.dateFromString(today)!
    let myCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    let myComponents = myCalendar.components(.Weekday, fromDate: todayDate)
    let weekDay = myComponents.weekday
    return weekDay
}
```

Y básicamente lo llamas así:

```
let weekday = getDayOfWeek(fecha)
```

Esto te devuelve un int que va de 1 a 7 (y creo que 1=Sunday) por lo que según el int que te devuelva la función:

> 1 - Domingo
>
> 2 - Lunes
>
> 3 - Martes
>
> 4 - Miércoles
>
> 5 - Jueves
>
> 6 - Viernes
>
> 7 - Sábado